# Add wishlist button to Virtuamart product list

Tags: php, jquery, joomla3.0, virtuemart

I'm using 
 1. Joomla 3.4.4
 2. Virtuamart 3.0.9

and I want to use send data from products sublayout in Virtuamart and send data with ajax to a controller.

```
var url = "?";
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery( ".wishlist-btn" ).click(function() {
    var productid = this.id;
    var userid = jQuery('input#user_id').val();
     var fav = {
            Productid: productid,
            Userid:userid
        }


    jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: { json: JSON.stringify(fav) },
            dataType: 'json',
contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });


});
```

but I don't know where should write PHP code,and what is the URL in my AJAX request.
I want to send profile id and user id to add in database for wishlist. 
I created a PHP file in

> com_virtuamar/controller/ajax.php

```
$json = $_POST['json'];
$person = json_encode($json);
echo $person->Userid;
```

and for URL in my AJAX request I used

> /components/com_virtuemart/controllers/ajax.php

but I think it's completely incorrect for address and usage in controller and also I don't know why userid doesn't return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are an error in your Ajax request. For send to PHP file, remove `data: { json: JSON.stringify(fav) }` and replace by:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(fav),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

and on your php file replace:

```
$person = json_encode($json);
```

by

```
$person = json_decode($json);
```

If you want access directly on Joomla session for get ID or Password user, you can check for

```
JFactory::getUser();
```

please see more: https://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getUser

Comment: thanks ,and what about the url ? wich controller i have to write my controller ?

Comment: you can use `url= "/ajax.php"` and put it on your root site folder or use the complet way `url= "http://yourdomain/components/com_virtuemart/controllers/ajax.php"`
if you want use `JFactory::getUser();` you can `define('_JEXEC', 1);`

Comment: $json = $_POST['json'];
$person = json_decode($json);
print_r($person);

Comment: var url = "/components/com_virtuemart/controllers/ajax.php";

Comment: ok, have you an error on your page? javascript or other? thanks

Comment: mm,the alert data is null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94294/discussion-between-p-frank-and-erfan-pj).